# Where do I put jinja2 helpers in a django 1.8 project?

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I'm currently upgrading django from 1.7.10 with jingo to 1.8.5 (actually from 1.6.x but I can now run the site with 1.7)

jingo no longer works with django 1.8 so I'm switching to the new Jinja2 support in django 1.8. I've reached a point where my templates are found and they are attempting to render using jinja2 but my helpers (`contextfunction`) are not found.

My `TEMPLATES` config looks like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'mysite', 'html'),
            os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'mysite', 'html', 'site')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': False,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'extensions': [
                'pipeline.templatetags.ext.PipelineExtension',
                'mysite.site.extensions.CacheTag',
                'mysite.site.extensions.CmsBlockTag',
            ],
            'extensions': [
                'jinja2.ext.autoescape',
                'jinja2.ext.do',
                'jinja2.ext.with_'
            ],
        },
    }
]
```

I currently have a file `mysite/site/helpers.py` that contains (amongst other functions and filters):

```
from jinja2 import contextfunction

@contextfunction
def upcase(text):
    return text.upper()
```

And a template:

```
<h3>{{ upcase('asdf') }}</h3>
```

I get the error `Exception Value: 'upcase' is undefined`.

How do I make the contents of the helpers file available?

Comment: I never found an answer to this. I ended up using the django-jinja pakage.